# IntelliJ - Running Program as Sudo

Tags: intellij-idea

Developing a program on OSX using Java and IntelliJ.  Deals with network sockets and ICMP.  Hence, the program needs to be run as root or sudo'd on OSX.  Program runs fine from a terminal window outside IntelliJ under sudo.  However,  I would like to debug and run it from IntelliJ (V9).  In IntelliJ it errors (I need root privs to enumerate network devices).  I know how to pass program and VM parameters in IntelliJ but now how to hit Run and/Debug and have it run under sudo?  What is needed is basically sudo java ...... MyProgram instead of java ..... MyProgram  Any ideas or workarounds.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I came out with an answer and wanted to share it just in case anyone else runs into this.  To solve the problem, I took my cue from what I do with QT & QT Creator when doing network programming.

On OSX, I opened up a terminal window and cd'd down to/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.3.app/Contents/MacOS.  There you will find a file called idea which launches the IDE.  I ran that as sudo (sudo ./idea).  That took care of permissions on anything Intellij launched and I could debug and step through my code as needed.

```
sudo /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.3.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
```

Since this is a dev machine and I am in control of it security is not an issue in this case.

Hope it helps someone else out.

Comment: Is there any way to make sure that IntelliJ always opens like this?

Comment: What is you wrote up a shell script with this line in it: sudo "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/Contents/MacOS/idea" &.  CHMOD the script to 755 and run Intellij from there as opposed to  using the normal icon

Comment: So for me it was creating problem because it was not starting intellij with logged in user, so I cd'd to `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.3.app/Contents/MacOS` and ran the idea script with logged in user and my problem was solved. Now I am looking forward to know what exactly happens when we open any application from spotlight search. Anyway, I spend 3-4 hours on this and this solution helped me.. So big hug to you brother. Thanks a ton.

Comment: In my case IntelliJ is a snap package, but the solution has been the same: 

`sudo /snap/bin/intellij-idea-community`

I needed to store some files into a root-owned folder. It worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Inside a terminal:

```
sudo -s
```

give access to the root user.

from there you could run the Idea IDE using the script:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA*/bin/idea.sh
```

and in this way I'm able to work on network where permission errors where printed before.

Comment: /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ *.app/Contents/MacOS/idea

Comment: Thank you, this was a life saver. Also, for some reason, when idea starts like this it starts fresh. which means all previous settings are gone. Wokraround was to export settings from previous running instance, save it as settings.zip and then import it from newly launched instance.

Answer (score 3):

Debugging of sudo programs is disallowed by the operating system unless the debugger is running as root, for security reasons.

So, even if you can figure out how to get IntelliJ to use sudo it won't do you any good.

Comment: I was hoping I could do something similar as I can in C++ and Qt.  I can launch a process and then attach the debugger to it.  In Qt Creator, I launch Qt Creator using sudo, run the program sudo with myprogram as a parameter to sudo, run myprogram from Qt Creator and then attach gdb to the running process.  Then I can step through it as needed.  No such luck in this case.  As you said, my debugger is running under root so it works.

Comment: To be clear. He is right that you can't debug a process that was started with sudo without running the debugger in sudo.

However, running intellij with sudo will work just fine, the risk is that any files made by the version running in "Sudo" will be owned by "root" which can cause issues if you're not always using sudo or a root user to write your code (which you probably shouldn't do). 

You should start a gdbserver and attach it to the process: `sudo gdbserver localhost:<SOME PORT> --attach <PID HERE>`

That command might be a little wrong, but it should get people there.

Comment: Your answer helped me but I do not understand the reason how. I am running IntelliJ with Sudo and visualvm with sudo as well. When I debug code with IntelliJ it unable to establish a connection with mem profiler (visualvm). I get unable to create socket error. 

But now, I am running program (i.e. not in debug mode) connection has been established between visualvm and my code.

Comment: Can you please help me out understand the reason, why this is happening and how can I resolve this problem. P.s: the problem you highlighted above "running version will be own by sudo" we have that problem here. I cant run my code without running intellij with sudo

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not what OP directly asked -
In case someone needs to do this on Linux (Ubuntu), e.g. in order to update Idea, just run from command line:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/idea
```

Only make sure once the Update and Restart is finished to actually close Idea and start it normally

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Darron, it is not recommended to execute IntelliJ with sudo.
You can execute with IntelliJ terminal instead.
I maintain my project in IntelliJ. When I need to execute a unit test that requires sudo access, I just open IntelliJ terminal and type:

```
sudo gradle test
```

Good luck!

Comment: >it is not recommended to execute IntelliJ with sudo. There's no real reason why the developer on his machine shouldn't be given access to run an IDE/debugger as a root user.