# Run commands that require root access from IntelliJ Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, root

I am working on a Java project together with other developers, all using macOS. As a part of its functionality, the code in this project needs to edit local `/etc/hosts` file which requires root user access. To accomplish that, we all run the IDE (IntelliJ) as root which creates a bunch of inconveniences.

I am really keen to find another solution to this problem. I had an idea to maybe somehow use a local environment variable (perhaps managed in IDE profile or something) but I am not sure how to do that.

Any ideas\suggestions how I can solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828036/is-there-a-way-for-a-java-app-to-gain-root-permissions

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413548/intellij-running-program-as-sudo

Comment: @DaveCarruthers please read my question again. This is exactly what we are doing right now and this is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Hope u have got the solution, But this answer might help others. Starting interllij using command `sudo ./idea.sh` will fix this issue. After staring the IDE use `su - <current user>` to switch back to the current user.

Note : u have to give the root user privilages to the current user. for that follow this [link](https://youtu.be/fnR4twMvGvc?t=4)